# If $(τ_n)$ is nondecreasing and $M$ is a martingale, then $\text E\left[\sum_n\left|M^{τ_n}_t-M^{τ_{n-1}}_t\right|^2\right]=\text E\left[M_t^2\right]$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, martingales, stopping-times

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a right-continuous filtration of $\mathcal A$
- $\tau_n$ be an $\mathcal F$-stopping time for $n\in\mathbb N_0$ with $$\tau_{n-1}\le\tau_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag1$$ and $$\tau_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty\tag2$$
- $M$ be a right-continuous $\mathcal F$-martingale on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$M_t\in L^2(\operatorname P)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag3$$

> I want to show that $$\operatorname E\left[\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left|M^{\tau_n}_t-M^{\tau_{n-1}}_t\right|^2\right]=\operatorname E\left[M_t^2\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\;.\tag4$$

Since $(\tau_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is nondecreasing, it's easy to see that $$\operatorname E\left[M_t^{\tau_n}-M_t^{\tau_{n-1}}\mid\mathcal F_{\tau_{n-1}}\right]=0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\text{ and }n\in\mathbb N\tag5$$ and hence $$\operatorname E\left[M_t^{\tau_n}-M_t^{\tau_{n-1}}\right]=0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\text{ and }n\in\mathbb N\;,\tag6$$ but I have no idea how we can show $(4)$. So, how can we prove it?

Comment: I take it that you assume $M_0 = 0$; otherwise it should read $\mathbb{E}(M_t^2)-\mathbb{E}(M_0^2)$ in $(4)$, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Using the martingale property show that $$\mathbb{E}((M_t^{\tau_n}-M_t^{\tau_{n-1}})^2) = \mathbb{E}((M_t^{\tau_n})^2)-\mathbb{E}((M_t^{\tau_{n-1}})^2).$$
2. By step 1, we have $$\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{n=1}^k |M_t^{\tau_n}-M_{t}^{\tau_{n-1}}|^2 \right) = \sum_{n=1}^k \bigg[ \mathbb{E}((M_t^{\tau_n})^2)-\mathbb{E}((M_t^{\tau_{n-1}})^2) \bigg].$$ Show that the right-hand side equals $$\sum_{n=1}^k \mathbb{E}(M_t^2 1_{\{\tau_{n-1} \leq t < \tau_n\}}) + \mathbb{E}(M_{\tau_k}^2 1_{\{t \geq \tau_k\}}).$$
3. Let $k \to \infty$ using the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Do you implicitly assume $\operatorname E\left[\left|M_{\tau_0}\right|^2\right]=0$ (or $\tau_0=0$ together with $M_0=0$)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes...otherwise your assertion $(4)$ is, in general, not correct.

Comment: Just to be sure: Let $(ω,t)∈ω\times[0,∞)$. If $t≤τ_0(ω)$, then $$M^{τ_n}_t(ω)=M_t(ω)\;\;\;\text{for all }n∈ℕ_0\;.\tag7$$ Otherwise, since $τ_n(ω)\xrightarrow{n\to∞}∞$, $\exists!n_0∈ℕ$ with $$t∈\left(τ_{n_0-1}(ω),τ_{n_0}(ω)\right]\tag8$$ and hence $$M_t^{τ_n}(ω)=\begin{cases}M_{τ_n(ω)}(ω)&\text{, if }n≤n_0-1\\M_t(ω)&\text{, if }n\ge n_0\end{cases}\tag9$$ for all $n∈ℕ_0$. Thus, $$\sum_{n=1}^N\left(|M_t^{τ_n}(ω)|^2-|M_t^{τ_{n-1}}(ω)|^2\right)=\begin{cases}|M_{τ_N(ω)}(ω)|^2-|M_{τ_0(ω)}(ω)|^2&\text{, if }N≤n_0-1\\|M_t(ω)|^2-|M_{τ_0(ω)}(ω)|^2&\text{, if }N≥n_0\end{cases}\tag{10}$$ for all $N∈ℕ$.

Comment: So, we should conclude that \begin{equation}\begin{split}\sum_{n=1}^N\left(|M_t^{τ_n}|^2-|M_t^{τ_{n-1}}|^2\right)&=1_{\left\{\:t\:>\:τ_N\:\right\}}|M_{τ_N}|^2\\&+\sum_{n=1}^N1_{\left\{\:τ_{n-1}\:<\:t\:≤\:τ_n\:\right\}}|M_t|^2-1_{\left\{\:t\:>\:τ_0\:\right\}}|M_{τ_0}|^2\end{split}\tag{11}\end{equation} for all $N∈ℕ$. Do you agree?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, I do.

Comment: If $X_n:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is $\mathcal F_{\tau_{n-1}}$-measurable with $|X_n|\le1$ almost surely for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $S^N:=\sum_{n=1}^NX_n\left(M^{τ_n}-M^{τ_{n-1}}\right)$ for $N\in\mathbb N$, the identity above yields that each $S^N$ is a square-integrable $\mathcal F$-martingale with $$\text E[|S_t^N|^2]\le\text E\left[1_{\left\{\:t\:>\:τ_0\:\right\}}\left(M_t^2-M_{\tau_0}^2\right)\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag{12}\;.$$ I've read that with this bound the martingale property of $S^N$ extends to $\lim_{N\to\infty}S^N$ "by uniform integrability". Do you know what's meant exactly?

Comment: @0xbadf00d You have to apply Vitali's convergence theorem: if $Y_n \to Y$ in probability (which is, in particular, satisfied in $Y_n \to Y$ almost surely) and $(Y_n)_n$ is uniformly integrable, then $Y_n \to Y$ in $L^1$. If you have any further questions on this please open a new question.

Comment: Ah, sure. $(12)$ yields the $L^2$-boundedness (and hence uniform integrability) of $(S_t^N)_{N\in\mathbb N}$. Thank you.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, exactly.